# Excel For Each ws not going to next ws

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Background -- I am working with a workbook with a whole bunch of sheets and a lot of data that is compromised of formulas. I am wanting to accomplish a few steps with this code:

- Unhide all hidden rows/columns
- Paste all data with ONLY values/formatting.

I am able to successfully complete these tasks on ONE worksheet, but it will not continue on -- it tries to continue repeating the same action on the same worksheet over and over.

```
Sub Macro1
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Have also tried "For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets at other users suggestions.
        ws.Cells.Activate
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
        ws.Cells.Activate
        ws.Cells.Copy
        ws.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        'I put these in here thinking that it might be related to the copying/pasting
        'action that was prohibiting it from changing sheets.

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Select  
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Greatly appreciate any help!!! I've been pulling hair out of my head (literally) for almost a week trying to troubleshoot this... I'm getting desperate! Thanks!

Comment: First code line inside the loop should be `ws.Activate` or `ws.Select` not `ws.Cells.Activate`. fwiw, neither actually looks necessary if you change `ActiveSheet.FilterMode` and `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` to `ws.FilterMode` and `ws.ShowAllData`.

Comment: What about ListObject tables? They could be filtered.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Sub Macro1
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
        ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you -- it's much more streamlined now too!

Comment: The code works - but how does it solve the OP question? This is a "code only" answer.